# Finding the zero of a function defined by a non linear differentiel equation (Question of numerical computation)

Tags: calculus

In my PHD studies, I need to find the zero of a mysterious function sigma defined by a differential equation of the following form
$$u*\sigma'(u)+(1-\chi_0)*\sigma(u)+\sum_{k=1}^{D}\sigma(u-x_k)(\chi_{k-1}-\chi_{k})=0,$$
with the initial condition $\sigma(u)=u^{chi(0)-1}$ if $u<=x_1$ and $\sigma(u)=0$ if $u<0$ in these two cases: ($D=10$ for both cases and $x_0=0$)
1) $x_k=1/(3*(D-k+1))$ and $$\chi_k=8* (\cos((2*(D-k)+3)π/(3*(D-k)+4)))^3-4* \cos((2*(D-k)+3)π/(3*(D-k)+4)).$$
2) $x_k= 1/(2*(D-k+1))$ and
$$\chi_k=16* \cos(((D-k)+2)π/(2*(D-k)+5))^4  -12*\cos(((D-k)+2)π/(2*(D-k)+5)))^2 +1.$$
I want just to mention that the sequence $(x_k)$ is increasing and we have 
$$x_0=0<x_1<x_2<...<x_D<X_{D+1}=+\infty.$$
Thank you.
Khadija

Comment: for the case 2) K1=K=10

Comment: [Please, allow others to read your posts](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, you can add precisations to it by clicking the "edit" button.